# VideoPlayer Autoplay SwiftUI Issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, autoplay

I am trying to get the `VideoPlayer` to autoplay with the video controller but I can't seem to figure it out! What should I do? I am fairly new to SwiftUI.

```
struct VideoView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    //: BINDING
    @Binding var videoView: Bool
    
    //: STATE
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    @State var isplaying = true
    @State var showcontrols = true
    
    //: VAR
    var allowsPictureInPicturePlayback : Bool = true
    var wrkflw: Wrkflw
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VideoPlayer(wrkflw: wrkflw, player: $player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
        
    }
}
```

**MARK: - VIDEO CONTROLLER**

```
struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var wrkflw: Wrkflw
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) ->  UIViewController {
        
        
        let player = AVPlayer(url: wrkflw.wrkvideo)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = true
        controller.exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true
        controller.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `play` on a *different instance* of `AVPlayer` -- see how you've created one in `VideoView` and then you create a different one inside `makeUIViewController`? They need to be the *same instance* if you're going to call `play()` on it like that.

Comment: Yes, I do see. Whether I take the instance away from VideoView or makeUIViewController, the conclusion is the same. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just pass the `AVPlayer` reference from your `VideoView` to the `VideoPlayer`. You can use `player.replaceCurrentItem` so that you can set the correct URL but maintain the same player reference.

Make sure you remove the `let player...` lines in `VideoPlayer`

```
struct VideoView: View { // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    //: BINDING
    
    @Binding var videoView: Bool
    
    //: STATE
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    @State var isplaying = true
    @State var showcontrols = true
    
    //: VAR
    var allowsPictureInPicturePlayback : Bool = true
    var wrkflw: Wrkflw
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VideoPlayer(wrkflw: wrkflw, player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
            .onAppear {
                player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: wrkflw.wrkvideo)) //<-- Here
                player.play()
            }
        
    }
}
// MARK: - VIDEO CONTROLLER

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var wrkflw: Wrkflw
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) ->  UIViewController {
        
        //<-- Here
        
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = true
        controller.exitsFullScreenWhenPlaybackEnds = true
        controller.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!  I was stomped!! You helped out a lot!! Thank you again!